# Scheme Function (DrRacket)

Tags: scheme, syntax-error, racket

So, i'm trying to write the following function in scheme, and to be able to run it on DrRacket. The problem is as follows,

**make5** - takes two integers, and returns a 5-digit integer constructed of the rightmost 3 digits of the first input, and the leftmost 2 digits of the second input. For example, (make5 561432 254) would return 43225.

Negative signs on either input number should be ignored - that is, (make5 561432 -254) would also return 43225.

If the first number has less than three digits or the last three digits start with zeros, and/or the second number has less two digits, your
function should return -2. Note: you may want to define some auxiliary functions.

So far this is the function I've been able to write.

```
(define (make5 x y)
  (cond ((< (length x) 3) -2)
        ((< (length y) 2) -2)
        (((modulo (abs(x)) 1000) 0) -2)
        (((modulo (abs(y)) 1000) 0) -2)
        (else (append (list-tail x 3) (cons (first(y)second(y)))))))
```

I'm getting the error...

*application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments*

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm new to scheme and still trying to grasp everything.

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap your arguments in parentheses - `(abs(x))` means "call the procedure `x` and pass the result to `abs`.
`(cons (first(y)second(y))` means "`cons` these *four* things: the value of `first`; the result of calling the procedure `y`; the value of `second`; and the result of calling the procedure `y`".
(You've called procedures correctly in some places. Stick to the same pattern.)

You're also missing a comparison in a couple of conditions; `(= (modulo (abs x) 1000) 0)`.

The inputs are not lists, they're integers, so you can't apply `length`, `first`, or any such things to them.
The result should be an integer, not a list, so you can't construct it using `append` and `cons`, you should only use arithmetic.

These facts about integers should get you started:

- A number has fewer than five digits if it is smaller than 10000.
- The last four digits of a non-negative number `n` is `(modulo n 10000)`.
- If `x` is 12 and `y` is 34, `x * 100 + y` is 1234.
- To get the three leftmost digit in an integer, you can divide by 10 repeatedly until you have a number less than 1000.

Also note that the second number only has one condition on its digits while the first has two, and that the note about defining auxiliary functions was not left there as a challenge for you to do without them.

For instance, if you had the auxiliary functions

- `(left-digits n x)`, which produces the leftmost `n` digits of `x`, and
- `(right-digits n x)`, which produces the rightmost `n` digits of `x`

you could write (it's also probably not a coincidence that the description uses the words "if" and "or"):

```
(define (make5 x y)
    (if (or ( ... ))
        -2
        (+ (* 100 (right-digits 3 x)) (left-digits 2 y))))
```

Since you want to ignore the sign of the numbers, it's convenient to take care of `abs` once at the start, using `let`:

```
(define (make5 signed-x signed-y)
    (let ((x (abs signed-x))
          (y (abs signed-y)))
        (if (or ( ... ))
            -2
            (+ (* 100 (right-digits 3 x)) (left-digits 2 y)))))
```

"All" that's left now is filling in the conditions and writing the two digit-extracting functions.

Comment: Thanks for the information you provided above, it has helped out. I was wondering if you could explain more on auxiliary functions? This is really giving me troubles with the problems I'm working with.

Comment: @Craig was this a helpful answer? if so, there's a big green V sign outline beside it you can click. Have another question? Post a new entry. That's how it works.