# DrRacket Function Program

Tags: scheme, racket

The description of the problem I am trying to solve is the following, 
    note: scheme functions should be written and be able to run in DrRacket

**make5** - takes two integers, and returns a 5-digit integer constructed of the rightmost 3 digits of the first input, and the leftmost 2 digits of the second input. For example, (make5 561432 254) would return 43225.

Negative signs on either input number should be ignored - that is, (make5 561432 -254) would also return 43225.

If the first number has less than three digits or the last three digits start with zeros, and/or the second number has less two digits, your function should return -2. Note: you may want to define some auxiliary functions.

The code I have so far is this,

```
(define (right-digits x)
  (* (modulo abs x 1000) 100))

(define (left-digits y)
  (modulo abs y 100))

(define (make5 x y)
  (cond ((= (modulo abs x 10000) 0)
           -2)
        ((= (modulo abs y 1000) 0)
           -2)
        (else make5(+ (* 100 (right-digits 3 x)) (left-digits 2 y)))))
```

When I test the function with something like (make5 12345 6789) I receive an error saying, "the expected number of arguments does not match the given number", "expected 2, given 3".

So somewhere I am messing up the argument, but I can't find the error.
Any help on how to get this puppy to work, let me know. Still learning, be gentle.

Comment: You're passing three arguments to `modulo` – you went from too many parentheses to too few. Review Scheme syntax in whatever learning materials you're using. Concentrate on getting `right-digits` correct first, then do `left-digits` (you're nowhere near on that one). (My answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47218016/scheme-function-drracket) gave you a fill-in-the-blanks solution. `make5` is not recursive.)

Answer (score 1):

You should test your helper functions first and then iterate forward when they are working. I am not gonna give you the full source code solution since you should learn something. Two hints:

1. You are calling `(modulo abs x 1000)` but the modulo function expects two arguments, you are handing over three.
2. What is abs for a variable in your case?

Comment: I didn't ask for your source code... As you can see from above I have been working on the function, and for quite a while now I might add. All I was asking is advice on why I am encountering that error. Thank you for the advice with the abs. I am hear to learn, but when I get stuck for hours, I thought best to ask someone else.

Comment: Sorry if you felt offended by my post Craig. It was not my intention. I just wanted to clearify why I am not just posting the correct solution. I hope you could solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a little off:

```
(define (right-digits x)
  (* (modulo abs x 1000) 100))
```

`modulo` takes 2 arguments and `abs` isn't even a number. What it is however is a function that when applied to a number evaluates to the absolute value. Perhaps you were actually thinking of using that function?

```
(define (right-digits x)
  (* (modulo (abs x) 1000) 100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another quote surrounding make5. This allows you to call the function and pass parameters.

```
(else (make5( (* 100 (right-digits 3 x)) (left-digits 2 y))))))
```